# Preventing children's default html styles being overridden

Tags: html, css, inheritance

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>
  div has pointer and sans-serif font
  <p>and paragraph also has it</p>
  <code>but code element doesn't have sans-serif font but pointer.</code>
</div>
```

`p` element has cursor `text` and `serif` as font-family as default. Both are being overridden.
`code` element has cursor `text` and `monospace` as font-family as default. Only cursor has been overridden.

Why does this happen? In `code` element, the `font-family` isn't overridden. Why? How can I set default html styles in certain chosen elements? (`p` and `code` elements here)

Apparently, even `all: revert` doesn't work!

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  all: revert;
}

code {
  all: revert;
}
```

```html
<div>
  div has pointer and sans-serif font
  <p>and paragraph also has it</p>
  <code>but code element doesn't have sans-serif font but pointer.</code>
</div>
```

`all: initial` works, but I don't want original CSS implementation applied. I want the user agent stylesheet rules applied. I used `revert` but to no avail.

Comment: Why not define the differences individually?

Comment: @Ugene Because that would produce a lot of redundant code that is already in user agent stylesheets.

Comment: But as long as the <p> and <code> tags are encapsulated by <div>. Your revert, unset will still return to those define for the <div> tag. Initial works because it returns the styles to their rock-bottom forms.

Comment: @Ugene Is there some way to take UA stylesheets into consideration and ignoring whatever parent it has got, and applying styles from UA stylesheet? Like ignoring `div` styles here?

Comment: Using classes or ids will make your life easier. This way you won't need to touch the base tag style.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN:

> By default, the content text is displayed using the user agent's
> default monospace font.

and:

> A CSS rule can be defined for the code selector to override the
> browser's default font face. Preferences set by the user might take
> precedence over the specified CSS.

So you do need to specify the font required specifically. If there is worry that the correct setting is not carried forward/may be changed in the future you could define it as a CSS variable so it only needs to have its value changed in one place.

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  --font: sans-serif;
  font-family: --font;
}

p {
  all: revert;
}

code {
  all: revert;
  font-family: --font;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  div has pointer and sans-serif font
  <p>and paragraph also has it</p>
  <code>and the code element also has sans-serif</code>
</div>
```

Comment: I just wanted a property or something that resets all the styles applied to an element and revert it to their default form, like specified by UA stylesheet. Isn't there something that does that? The cursor seems to still be pointer with your code ...

Comment: Apologies, I thought it was that way round that you wanted. I'll delete this answer shortly.